# Zip stating absolute paths, but only keeping part of them

Tags: linux, zip

```
zip -r 1.zip /home/username/the_folder
```

At here, when i unzip `1.zip`, it will create `/home/username/the_folder`, from whichever folder i am unzipping from.

How do I zip, stating the full absolute paths, but make the zip only contain the folder structure starting at, in this case for instance, `/home/username`?

That way I could be at whatever path i wanted, unzip and it would just create `the_folder`, and not `/home/username/the_folder`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this command:

```
cd path_under_folder_to_zip && \
zip -r 1.zip folder_to_zip >/dev/null && \
mv 1.zip my_current_path
```

Comment: cd path_under_folder_to_zip && zip -r my_current_path/1.zip folder_to_zip >/dev/null

Comment: Works great on macOS :) Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use relative path when specifying the file to zip.

```
cd /home/username
zip -r 1.zip ./the_folder
```

Then when you unzip, it'll be a relative path starting at whichever folder you're in when unzipping.

Comment: He wants to be able to use absolute path. Please note 'whatever path i wanted'. Though what you are saying makes sense.

Comment: Not right by this theme, but that light solution helped me. Thank you for that idea!

Answer (score 1):

1. List item

How about this:

```
function zipExtraFolder {
    if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        echo "provide at least two arguments"
        return
    fi
    folder=$2
    mkdir del
    echo cp -r `dirname $folder` del
    cd del
    echo zip -r ../$1 .
    cd -
    rm -rf del
}
```

Define above as a shell function in your .bashrc and you should be able to use it whenever you want.
The usage will be like below.

```
zipExtraFolder 1.zip /home/username/the_folder
```

Comment: I can't really read that code, and won't this cause problems when i start making more complex zip commands?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `-j` option, works on `OSX`, I don't know about linux.

`zip -j -r 1.zip /home/username/the_folder`

Comment: i get an error, apparently because there are two instances of a file with the same name within that folder. Even though they are in different sub folders.

Comment: I had forgotten, the `-j` option is not practical when using with the `-r` option, because it compresses all files in the root folder without the folder structure.

Comment: if `-j` doesn't work for you checkout [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/119661/45285)